# Save a Django ModelForm with default fields values in Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model `FooModel` with 2 fields with a default value (`default=xxx`) and marked as blank (`blank=True`), I created a `ModelForm`(`django.forms.ModelForm`) using `FooModel` and now I want to save it after submission, so in my view I have the following code:

```
f = FooForm(request.POST)

if f.is_valid():
  f.save()
```

the problem is that in this way I get a violation exception from the database because the fields that are not rendered in the html form are not automatically inherited in the FooForm instance as I would expect... how can I include fields from the original model which should not be displayed to the user? (I don't want to render them as hidden fields!)

So far I tried 2 approaches, both failed...

1. Specify instance in the FooForm constructor (`f = FooForm(request.POST, instance=FooModel())`)
2. Create an instance of a FooModel and manually assign the auto-generated values to the form's data:

   ```
   i = FooModel()

   f.data.fieldA = i.fieldA

   f.data.fieldB = i.fieldB
   ```

**UPDATE:**

by reading the django documentation more accurately, I solved in this way:

```
if f.is_valid():
  formModel = f.save(commit=False)
  foo = FooModel()
  formModel.fieldA = foo.fieldA
  formModel.fieldB = foo.fieldB
  formModel.save()
```

but, to be honest, I'm not satisfied... I would like to abstract out the addition of those fields... perhaps by using a custom decorator... something like:

```
f = MissingFieldsDecorator(FooForm(request.POST))
f.save()
```

Comment: Have you tired the approach specified here
[link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form)

Comment: could you please post your comment as an answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also try the approach mentioned here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form

Answer (score 0):

> how can I include fields from the original model which should not be displayed to the user?

Answering this part of your question

```
class FooForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FooModel
        exclude = ('not_displayed_field',)
```

Comment: This would exclude the field not, hide it != "include fields from the original model". Use  widgets = {
            'not_displayed_field': forms.HiddenInput()
        }